# Running a Bash script over ssh

Tags: bash, scripting, ssh

I'm trying to write a Bash script that will SSH into a machine and create a directory. The long-term goal is a bit more complicated, but for now I'm starting simple. However, as simple as it is, I can't quite seem to get it. Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -T tunneluser@111.222.333.444 <<EOI

# Fix "TERM environment variable undefined" error.
TERM=dumb
export TERM

# Store todays date.
NOW=$(date +"%F")
echo $NOW

# Store backup path.
BACKUP="/backup/$NOW"
[ ! -d $BACKUP ] && mkdir -p ${BACKUP}
echo $BACKUP

exit
EOI
```

It runs without any explicit errors. However, the echoed $NOW and $BACKUP variables appear empty, and the /backup directory is not created. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The shell on the local host is doing variable substitution on $NOW and $BACKUP because the "EOI" isn't escaped.  Replace

```
 ssh tunneluser@111.222.333.444 <<EOI
```

with

```
 ssh tunneluser@111.222.333.444 <<\EOI
```

Comment: Thanks. This required the fewest changes, and works perfectly.

Comment: Do either of you have an example that allows variables passed into the ssh session? For instance, if I had the block @Cerin used earlier in a bash script and before the `ssh ...` I declare `REMOTE_PATH=root/stuff/buildpath` , can I use `$REMOTE_PATH` or the like inside my ssh / heredoc ?

Comment: @Brian, Using hbar's example below, if you just don't escape $REMOTE_PATH, then it should be inserted into the ssh script ran on the remote server.

Comment: In addition to \, we can also use single quotes to wrap the LimitString, in this case EOI to escape special characters in here documents, for example `ssh tunneluser@111.222.333.444 <<'EOI'`.

Answer (score 21):

The variables are being evaluated in the script on the local machine.  You need to subsitute the dollar signs with escaped dollar signs.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -T tunneluser@111.222.333.444 <<EOI

# Fix "TERM environment variable undefined" error.
TERM=dumb
export TERM

# Store todays date.
NOW=\$(date +"%F")
echo \$NOW

# Store backup path.
BACKUP="/backup/\$NOW"
[ ! -d \$BACKUP ] && mkdir -p \${BACKUP}
echo \$BACKUP

exit
EOI
```

Comment: Perfect :) :) Explanation ... I think this makes rest of the discussion pretty useless ..

Answer (score 6):

Your script is doing substitution on the local host before being sent over.

Change your first line to:

```
ssh -T tunneluser@111.222.333.444 <<'EOI'
```

This will cause the raw script to get sent over and interpreted on your remote host.

If you wanted a mix (so for example, if you wanted the `date` command executed on your local host, you should leave ssh line unchanged and quote the individual command):

```
ssh -T tunneluser@111.222.333.444 <<EOI

# Execute the date command on the local machine.  The assignment still
# happens on the remote machine
NOW=$(date +"%F")

# Quote your $ so that the replacement happens on the remote machine
echo \$NOW
```

Comment: Your second example quotes the here-doc delimiter and the variable. I think you intended to only escape the variable. Otherwise +1

Answer (score 0):

## How to run a local script over SSH

### Synopsis:

Script execution over SSH without copying script file.
You need a simple SSH connexion and a local script.

### Code:

```
#!/bin/sh
print_usage() {
        echo -e "`basename $0` ssh_connexion local_script"
        echo -e "Remote executes local_script on ssh server"
        echo -e "For convinient use, use ssh public key for remote connexion"
        exit 0
}

[ $# -eq "2" ] && [ $1 != "-h" ] && [ $1 != "--help" ] || print_usage

INTERPRETER=$(head -n 1 $2 | sed -e 's/#!//')

cat $2 | grep -v "#" | ssh -t $1 $INTERPRETER
```

### Examples:

- ssh-remote-exec root@server1 myLocalScript.sh #for Bash
- ssh-remote-exec root@server1 myLocalScript.py #for Python
- ssh-remote-exec root@server1 myLocalScript.pl #for Perl
- ssh-remote-exec root@server1 myLocalScript.rb #for Ruby

### Step by step explanations

This script performs this operations:
1° catches first line #! to get interpreter (i.e: Perl, Python, Ruby, Bash interpreter),
2° starts remote interpeter over SSH,
3° send all the script body over SSH.

### Local Script:

Local script must start with #!/path/to/interpreter
 - #!/bin/sh for Bash script
 - #!/usr/bin/perl for Perl script
 - #!/usr/bin/python for Python script
 - #!/usr/bin/ruby for Ruby script

This script is not based on local script extension but on #! information.

Comment: What's with all the `-e`s? POSIX doesn't require `echo -e` to do anything but print `-e` on output; in fact, doing anything else is *explicitly noncompliant*, and bash can be configured at either compile-time or runtime to comply with the letter of the standard, so  behavior of `echo -e` is undefined and widely variable. (If your `/bin/sh` is provided by `dash` instead of `bash`, you'll get the POSIX-compliant behavior, so output will have a bunch of `-e` strings in it with this script written as it is).

Comment: Consider also running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing the quoting issues it identifies.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
NOW=`date +"%F"`
```

Comment: `$()` is the same as `` except the former easily allows nesting.  This is something any POSIX-compliant sh can handle.

Comment: @GreenMatt, not just "newer bash versions", **all** shells compliant with the 1992 POSIX sh standard.

Comment: @GreenMatt, sure, but you were speaking about *bash* specifically, so we're not talking about Bourne here. And I'm not aware of *any* released version of bash that lacked `$(...)`; it was certainly there in 2.0, and isn't listed as a change from 1.x either, making it presumptively something that wasn't new even then.