# Bash: how to run a script remotely

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script (say `run.py`) and I want to scp that to a remote machine (say `10.1.100.100`), cd into a directory in that remote machine, and execute `run.py` in that directory.

How do I wrap the above procedure in one single bash script? I don't know how to let bash execute commands remotely in another machine.

Hopefully I can see that stdout of `run.py` in my terminal. But if I can only redirect it, that's fine as well.

Comment: You should use ssh connection like in the this [question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2374276/944000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
chmod +x ./run.py
scp -pq  ./run.py 10.1.100.100:'/home/myremotedirectory/run.py'
ssh 10.1.100.100     'cd /somedirectory  &&  /home/myremotedirectory/run.py'
```

See if that helps

Comment: You could also send the script as standard input and `ssh remote 'cat >tmp; chmod +x tmp; tmp'` but the remote temp file handling should be a bit more involved than this crude proof of concept, which also doesn't include the `cd`. Note also that some sites specifically disallow executables in `/tmp`.

Answer (score 3):

## How to run a local script over SSH

### Synopsis:

Script execution over SSH without copying script file.
You need a simple SSH connexion and a local script.

### Code:

```
#!/bin/sh
print_usage() {
        echo -e "`basename $0` ssh_connexion local_script"
        echo -e "Remote executes local_script on ssh server"
        echo -e "For convinient use, use ssh public key for remote connexion"
        exit 0
}

[ $# -eq "2" ] && [ $1 != "-h" ] && [ $1 != "--help" ] || print_usage

INTERPRETER=$(head -n 1 $2 | sed -e 's/#!//')

cat $2 | grep -v "#" | ssh -t $1 $INTERPRETER
```

### Examples:

```
 - ssh-remote-exec root@server1 myLocalScript.sh #for Bash
 - ssh-remote-exec root@server1 myLocalScript.py #for Python
 - ssh-remote-exec root@server1 myLocalScript.pl #for Perl
 - ssh-remote-exec root@server1 myLocalScript.rb #for Ruby
```

### Step by step explanations

This script performs this operations:
1° catches first line #! to get interpreter (i.e: Perl, Python, Ruby, Bash interpreter),
2° starts remote interpeter over SSH,
3° send all the script body over SSH.

### Local Script:

Local script must start with #!/path/to/interpreter

```
- #!/bin/sh for Bash script
 - #!/usr/bin/perl for Perl script
 - #!/usr/bin/python for Python script
 - #!/usr/bin/ruby for Ruby script
```

This script is not based on local script extension but on #! information.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
ssh -l yourid 10.1.100.100 << DONE
cd /your/dir/
./run.py
DONE
```

Above has been edited, I don't remember what it was like originally, if I want to do it in one single connection, I will do it this way.

```
ssh -l yourid 10.1.100.100 python < <(
echo "import os"
echo "os.chdir('/yourdir')"
echo "print(os.getcwd())"
cat yourscript.py
)
```

Comment: This requires `run.py` to already be present on the remote machine. Easy to fix, but not a complete answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, that this is not a rule, that you HAVE TO cd to the requested directory.

Once you get access to the remote machine, just type a relative path to this file, without using cd:

```
/some_folder/./run.py
```