# Passing quotes and other special characters literally through bash and ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, lua

I am trying to run an SSH command that will invoke a script on a remote machine that writes some Lua code to a file.

I have this script command that executes under bash:

```bash
ssh bob writelua.sh '{version=1,{["foo"]=17}}'
```

And `writelua.sh` looks like this:

```bash
echo "return $1" > bar.lua
```

The end result, however, is that `bar.lua` has the content:

```lua
return version=1
```

I had thought that single quotes prevented all interpretation. How can I edit the scripts and escaping to pass the raw Lua code through unharmed?

Comment: There are multiple points where interpretation is possible, so for each of those points, a layer of escaping might be needed: `ssh bob "writelua.sh '{version=1,{[\"foo\"]=17}}'"` (or `ssh bob 'writelua.sh "{version=1,{[\"foo\"]=17}}"'`)

Comment: Perhaps it's going through one more level of "interpretation". Did you try escaping the single quotes (*i.e.*, `'{version=1,{["foo"]=17}}\'`)

Answer (score 4):

The single quotes prevent interpretation on the *local* host. The remote host sees the command line

```
writelua.sh {version=1,{["foo"]=17}}
```

which is subject to brace expansion. You need a second set of quotes so that the first set of single quotes is passed through to the remote host.

```
ssh bob writelua.sh "'{version=1,{[\"foo\"]=17}}'"
```

As you can see, the quotes start to get unwieldy. A better solution is to simply copy a script containing

```
writelua.sh '{version=1,{["foo"]=17}}'
```

to the remote host and execute that remotely.

---

An example using the `$'...'` quotes:

```
ssh bob writelua.sh $'{version=1,{[\'foo\']=17}}'
```

Comment: What if I have single quotes in my content? I cannot put single quotes in my single quotes, even escaped. (Right?)

Comment: If you have single quotes in the content, it's an even better idea to simply write a small script that is copied. `bash` has Yet Another Quoting Mechanism that can include single quotes (`$'\'foo\''`), but it's really better to just stop abusing the poor command line and wrap it in a script.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the local file system, and therefore I cannot write a file to invoke. I only have the ability to execute a command. :/

Comment: I can accept this answer, since I am able to solve it for my code with some special knowledge of the wrapping quotes and escaping of the parameters...but I'd love an answer (which may not exist) that worked for arbitrary code content without modifying the string itself.

Comment: Are you really hard-coding the value to pass to `writelua.sh` when you call `ssh`? The fact that you are trying to pass a quoted string through two shells means something needs to introduce the escaped quotes.

Comment: @Phrogz perhaps something like `ssh bob dd of=script.sh <<EOF ...script content here... EOF; ssh bob ./script.sh'

Comment: The same quoting issues apply to the contents of the here document.

Comment: @chepner Not hard-coded, no. `os.execute(string.format('ssh %s writelua.sh "\'%s\'"',server,lua))`; so, now `lua` is required to have no single quotes, and double-quotes escaped. Works for my current limited, controlled circumstances.

Comment: You are passing this to `os.execute` as well? You failed to mention that before. Is this Python? I'm not aware of an `os.execute` function, but it looks like Python.

Answer (score 2):

Use `heredoc` and **avoid all the excessive quoting**:

```
ssh -T bob << \EOF
    writelua.sh '{version=1,{["foo"]=17}}'
EOF
```

This will send raw script to remote host and it will get interpreted on the remote host itself.

Comment: @Phrogz: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374276/running-a-bash-script-over-ssh for related info.

Comment: I just tried above heredoc and got `return {version=1,{["foo"]=17}}` in the `bar.lua` on remote host.

Comment: You can modify `writelua.sh` to `echo "return '$1'"` if you want the quotes written to the file itself. (Techinically, the quotes are passed to the remote host, where they are stripped before setting `$1` for `writelua.sh`, so you need to add them back again.)

Answer (score 0):

When it gets too complex, particularly with lots of escaping, I prefer generating the command on a temporary script and execute it locally or remotely via SSH as required.

But there's an alternative: using `echo` to store the command in a variable and taking advantage of three things:

- Single quotes don't do variable expansion and allow double quotes, so you can include something like `"$myvar"` without escaping `$` or `"`
- Double quotes allow variable expansion and single quotes, which means you can include something like `animals='all'; echo love $animals` to have `$animals` replaced by its value, and without escaping the `'`
- Strings of both types, i.e. enclosed by single quotes or double quotes, can be concatenated simply by putting them together.

As an example, if I want something like this executed on a remote machine:

```
source /my-env.sh; perl -MMYLIB::DB -e 'my $t=db_list("name", 1553786458); print "@$t"'
```

But instead of `1553786458` I want to pass the value from a local variable:

```
now=`date +%s`
```

We could have this:

```
get_list=`echo 'source /my-env.sh; perl -MMYLIB::DB -e' "'my " '$t=db_list("name", ' "$now" '); print "@$t"' "'"`
```

You can see that single and double quotes are alternated, so we din't have to do any escaping! They don't need to be separated by spaces, but it improves readability and won't affect the result in this case.

And now we can execute:

```
ssh user@host $get_list
```

There's still no guarantee that this approach will always work, so once you've built your command, the safest bet would be to copy it over in a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Perl...

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("bob");
$ssh->system('writelua.sh', '{version=1,{["foo"]=17}}')
  or die $ssh->error;
```

[Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH) takes care of [quoting](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#Shell-quoting) everything for you.