# Execute script over SSH and get output?

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, sh

I am trying to execute a command in a remote machine and get the output.

I have tried implementing below shell script but unable to get the content.

```
#!/bin/bash

out=$(ssh huser@$source << EOF
while IFS= read -r line
do
echo 'Data : ' $line
done < "data.txt"
EOF
)

echo $out
```

### Output:

```
Data : Data : Data :
```

I could see the "Data :" is printed 3 times because the file "data.txt" has 3 lines of text.

I can't use scp command to get the file directly because I might have to run some command in the place of text file.

Can someone help me in finding the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you put four spaces at the start of each line of your code, instead of ">", it will format better. Or remove the >s and hit the `{}` button.

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend.

Comment: ...big chunks of this are duplicative of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374276/running-a-bash-script-over-ssh -- the rest is just the quoting on the expansion on the `echo`.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem doesn't have anything to do with ssh at all:

```
echo $out
```

is mangling your data. Use quotes!

```
echo "$out"
```

---

Similarly, you need to quote your heredoc:

```
out=$(ssh huser@$source <<'EOF'
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf 'Data : %s\n' "$line"
  done < "data.txt"
EOF
)
```

Using `<<'EOF'` instead of `<<EOF` prevents `$line` from being expanded locally, *before* the code has been sent over SSH; this local expansion was replacing `echo 'Data : ' $line` with `echo 'Data : '`, because on your local system the `line` variable is unset.