# Capture output of bash script over ssh within script

Tags: bash, ssh

I am aware of this discussion:
[Running A Bash Script Over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374276/running-a-bash-script-over-ssh)

However, I have a somewhat varied take on it - and it's got me stumped.

I have an ssh alias in my ~/.ssh/config called remServer to which I can ssh just fine.  I'd like to run some remote commands on that server and deal with the output on the local server.

My problem comes to substituting variables into the ssh commands (such an elementary subject) but I'm missing something here.

Here's the issue:

```
#this works
op="ls"
cmd="ssh remServer '$op'"
res=`$cmd`
echo $res

#this doesn't
op="ls -lt"
cmd="ssh remServer '$op'"
res=`$cmd`
echo $res
```

No matter how many ways I use single or double quotes, I only get back something along the lines of:

> bash ls -lt command not found

Comment: What happens when you run `ssh remServer 'ls'` interactively? Could you check in the shell configuration files (.bashrc and so on) on the remote system to see if there is an alias for the `ls` command?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your viewing.  Running interactively, I get a simple listing of files (as expected) - just as I do when on the remote server itself (so nothing changing the ls command there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you pass in literal single quotes, the command executed becomes `'ls -lt'` which gives the same error locally too (as opposed to `ls -lt` without quotes).

The easiest solution is just removing the quotes:

```
op="ls -lt"
cmd="ssh remServer $op"
res=`$cmd`
echo $res
```

The better solution is using proper arrays and escaping:

```
op=(ls -lt)
cmd=(ssh remServer "$(printf '%q ' "${op[@]}")" )
res=$("${cmd[@]}")
echo "$res"
```