# Is there a way through which i can access,use and manipulate files from one server using shell scripting on another server >

Tags: shell, ssh

I tried accessing files from `remote server "10.101.28.83"` and manipulating files to create folders on host server where script has been run. But `*` is the output of **echo "$(basename "$file")"** command which implies that files are not read from remote server.

```
#!/bin/bash
#for file in /root/final_migrated_data/*; do
for file in root@10.101.28.83:/root/final_migrated_data/* ; do
echo "$(basename "$file")"
IN="$(basename "$file")"
IFS='_'
read -a addr <<< "$(basename "$file")"
# addr[0] is case_type, addr[1] is case_no, addr[2] is case_year
dir_path="/newdir1";
backup_date="${addr[0]}_${addr[1]}_${addr[2]}";
backup_dir="${dir_path}/${backup_date}";
mkdir -p "${backup_dir}";
cp /root/final_migrated_data/"${backup_date}"_* "${backup_dir}"

done
```

I expect the output of **echo "$(basename "$file")"** to be the list of files present at the location `/root/final_migrated_data/` of remote server but the actual output is `*` .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a Bash script over ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374276/running-a-bash-script-over-ssh)

Comment: you want to execute that loop on your remote machine and you'll need to use `ssh` to do that. `root@10.101.28.83 'cd /root/final_migrated_data; for file in * l do .... ; done`. Search here for Q/A on how to setup your `ssh` access. It can be confusing and frustrating the first time. See if someone else in your area can show you how. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **sshfs**. As the name suggests, sshfs allows to mount locally (both for reading and writing) a distant filesystem to which you have SSH access. As long as you already know SSH, its usage is very straightforward:

```
# mount the distant directory on your local machine:
sshfs user@server.com:/my/directory /local/mountpoint
# manipulate the filesystem just like any other (cd, ls, mv, rm…)
# unmount:
umount /local/mountpoint
```

If you need to mount the same distant filesystem often, you can even add it to your `/etc/fstab`, refer to the documentation for how to do it.

Note however that using an SSH filesystem is slow, because each operation on the filesystem implies fetching or sending data through the network, and sshfs is not particularly optimized against that (it does not cache file contents, for instance). [Other solutions exist](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62677/best-way-to-mount-remote-folder), which may be more complex to set up but offer better performance.

See by yourself whether speed is a problem. In your case, if you are simply copying files from one place in your server to another place in your server, it seems rather absurd to make it transit through your home computer and back again. It may be more advantageous to simply run your script on your server directly.