# How to send files continuously from one folder to another in a running container to be shown as a static data through a browser?

Tags: shell, logging, containers, openshift, lifecycle

I am trying to send files in /logs folder from my container continuously to /var/httpd-resources/static/ folder. For that I am using an infinite while loop in postStart option in container :

while true; do rsync -avh /logs/ /var/httpd-resources/static/; sleep 1; done

But container is not running like this, and I am not able to sync the folders also

How can I send files in /logs folder continuously to required folder? Is there any way I can write a shell command which can be run continuosly in loop (or cron job) in my running container?

```
 - name: httpd
          image: ${IMAGE}
          command: [ "/bin/sh" ]
          args: [ "-c", "/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/httpd-conf/httpd.conf -DFOREGROUND" ]
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
          # TODO: Should we be using trailing slashes?
          - name: logs
            mountPath: "/logs/"
          - name: resources
            mountPath: "/var/httpd-resources/"
          - name: httpd-conf
            mountPath: "/etc/httpd-conf/"
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command:
                  - "sh"
                  - "-c"
                  - >
                    if [ ! -e "/logs/access_log_rotated_at_50M" ] ; then
                      touch /logs/access_log_rotated_at_50M
                    fi;
                    if [ ! -e "/logs/error_log_rotated_at_5M" ] ; then
                      touch /logs/error_log_rotated_at_5M
                    fi;
                    while true; do rsync -avh /logs/ /var/httpd-resources/${APPLICATION_PATH}/; sleep 1; done 
          readinessProbe:
            ...................................
          livenessProbe:
            .................................
          resources:
            ..................................
```

Comment: you'll need to be more specific about your meaning *send files in /logs folder **continuously** to required folder* . Will the files be complete and not change again or will the files keep growing over time. If keep growing, then how do you determine a good/safe time to make a transfer. If really continuous, the you need a real time solution. Could your local machine get an NFS mount to that directory on the logging machine? Or you could run `tail -f logFile.txt` and send the output via a remote shell (ssh). Please update the body of your Q above, rather than reply in comments. Good luck.

Comment: And it is unclear what software reads the "code" you have included in your Q. That isn't `shell` code, although it contains shell code. Good luck.

Comment: Hmm (I didn't know about sshfs).. just saw this today https://stackoverflow.com/a/57602929/620097 maybe it can help. Good luck.